# Angular 2 : Data transfer through service

Tags: angular, angular-services

I have an angular service which has two fields namely "itemName" and "quantity".

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class NetworkService {

  public itemName:String;
  public quantity:String;

  constructor() {

   }

 setItem(name:string,value:string){
      this.itemName = name;
     this.quantity = value;
     console.log("Set Item called name = "+this.itemName+" value = "+this.quantity);

   }
}
```

From my component EditentryComponent, I am calling the service method setItem().

```
import { Component, OnInit, ElementRef, ViewChild  } from '@angular/core';

import { NetworkService } from './../services/network.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-editentry',
  templateUrl: './editentry.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./editentry.component.css'],
  providers : [NetworkService]
})

export class EditentryComponent implements OnInit {

constructor(private networkservice : NetworkService) {
}

ngOnInit():void {
}

getItems(){
 this.networkservice.setItemToEdit("apple","10");
 this.router.navigate(['/editreceipt']);
}

}
```

And from second component I try to get the values set by first component as -

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NetworkService } from './../services/network.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-edit-receipt-component',
  templateUrl: './edit-receipt-component.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./edit-receipt-component.component.css'],
  providers : [NetworkService]

})
export class EditReceiptComponentComponent implements OnInit {

constructor(private networkservice : NetworkService) { 
}

ngOnInit() {
  console.log("Item name = "+this.networkservice.itemName);
}

}
```

But I get **"Item name = undefined"** as the output from second component. Where am I going wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating two separate instances of the service by including them in the providers of each component

```
providers: [NetworkService]
```

You need to use a singleton instance of the service and only initialize the service in your app.module. So try removing the services from your providers of your components

Comment: thank you for your answer. I removed providers from my individual components and put it inside providers of app.module.ts. It worked !!!

Answer (score 0):

You have two services instances. 
One for each component. You need to declare your NetworkService in a higher level (e.g. In the module or a parent component).

For more information , see: https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection

Answer (score 0):

To have singleton service you must declare it on module level and remove it from component providers declaration. In your case it is initialized by Angular as service with local scope.